# DraggableViews questions

Tags: views

If I followed the README.txt in the module and created a view with a sorting field as instructed, should I be able to drag the items around with a four-way cursor, and then Save? I do see the Save button, but no ability to drag...

Also, is there a way to have [DraggableView](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) come into play for a view which uses display mode (teasers) rather than fields? (I do have my own CCK field named "weight", which I could make use of and get away without DV, so it's just a question of how to make admin UI easier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you should get the four-way cursor and be able to drag stuff around. My own experience has been that DW for D7 is quite buggy. We use a particular commit in [NodeStream's makefile](http://drupalcode.org/project/nodestream.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/drupal-org.make), you could try to work from that one, as we do our best to keep well working versions in that make file.
2. I don't think you can use a View mode, but must use fields. I could be wrong though.

Comment: I followed the instructions on http://drupal.org/node/283498, and a smile came up on my face when I saw in the preview pane a whole list of four-way icon items. The smile went away, when I shit Save and saw the PDOException notice. So - yes, it's quite buggy - I take that as an answer. I will try to use the makefile some time later, when I get my site up and running and get some more git expertise. Thanks though!

Comment: You don't need to use the entire makefile though. I just refered to it rather than a specific commit as we might move what we consider "the best commit" later.